# Which version of the Gospels do the authors of the Philokalia refer to?

Tags: church-history, eastern-orthodox, gospels

Which version of the Gospels do the authors of the [*Philokalia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philokalia) (such as Gregory Palamas) refer to? Clearly this would be some Greek version.

But I would like to know what would be the closest thing to that version, today. Both original greek versions and translation from those would be an acceptable answer. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for contributing. Could you clarify what you mean by "closest thing to that version, today"?  Do you mean an English translation?  If you haven't already done so, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: Do you mean which OT translation (LXX) they refer to, or which codex of NT?

Comment: Both! I am asking a very general question, because I wonder what would they read and where do the quotations in the english (or Russian) translation come from.

Comment: If you are asking about the OT as well, then the question needs to be updated to say that, rather than "gospels" as it does now.

Comment: This is an extremely broad question, but the best guess is the text still considered authoritative in Eastern Orthodoxy today, the authorized 1904 text of the Ecumenical Patriarchate of Constantinople. This is [available for free online](http://www.goarch.org/chapel/biblegreek) and [you can purchase it on Logos](https://www.logos.com/product/32420/the-patriarchal-greek-new-testament) and other print or electronic editions also. Most of the print editions are self-published so buyer beware. Some have begun [an English translation from these texts also](http://www.orthodox-church.info/eob)

Comment: For a slightly more scholarly text that has a similar philosophy of preserving the Byzantine text-type ("Majority" text) with a reliance on lectionaries over modern textual criticism methods, also check out [the Robinson/Pierpont Byzantine Textform.](https://www.amazon.com/New-Testament-Original-Greek/dp/0759800774) You can probably find it free online - I believe they released it public domain at some point.

Comment: However, with all that said, I believe there are clear indications from textual criticism that this textform *has been* altered since the time it was read by Palamas and other early Fathers, and there are numerous scholarly projects devoted to textual criticism which attempt to determine this. The most notable examples include the [*Comma Johanneum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_Johanneum) and [*Pericope Adulterae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_and_the_woman_taken_in_adultery#Textual_history). Ancient manuscript copying was far more error-prone than modern printing presses.

Answer (score 2):

It is almost impossible that the writers of *The Philokalia* consulted exactly the same Gospel manuscripts.  It is a collection of writings from over 20 different authors spanning almost 1,000 years from different locations around the Mediterranean and Middle East.

For example: Isaiah the Solitary lived in Gaza in the 5th century; John Cassian lived in Gaul in the 4th and 5th centuries; John of Damascus in Syria in the 8th century; Gregory Palamas in Greece and Constantinople in the 14th century.

The 1904 *Patriarchal Text* mentioned in the comments was compiled from a number of disparate Greek texts and lectionaries that had been in use over the last two millennium.  It does not claim itself to be any kind of "original text".  In content it ends up being closest to the Majority Text.